# What is REPARTITION in BigQuery excution plan?

Tags: google-bigquery

While exceuting query, In BigQuery execution plan, I am getting new stage named "**REPARTITION**"

Can anyone help me out to understand meaning of the term "REPARTITION" in that.

You can refer below image for more detail.

[REPARTITION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHMkZ.png)

Answer (score 4):

From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation#background):

> Another important property of the query execution architecture is that
>   it is dynamic, which means that the query plan may be modified while a
>   query is in flight. Stages that are introduced while a query is
>   running are often used to improve data distribution throughout query
>   workers. In query plans where this occurs, these are typically labeled
>   as Repartition stages.